# Trying to run a node-express server to send emails and getting infinte loop

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to run the server in the above title,
and I seem to get an infinite loop with the server restarting itself every second.
Please help and tell me what I am doing wrong I am new to node-express.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const sendGridTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');
const { SENDGRID_API } = require('./config/keys');
// const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(express.json());
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
  sendGridTransport({
    auth: {
      api_key:
        'hidden',
    },
  })
);
const postMail = router.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  const { data, ingredients, price } = req.body;
  transporter
    .sendMail({
      to: 'hidden@hidden.com',
      from: 'hidden@hidden.com',
      subject: `הזמנה מ:${data.fullName}`,
      html: `<h3>שלום יש לך הזמנה חדשה !</h3>
<p>פרטי משלוח:</p>
<p>שם:${data.fullName}</p>
<p>עיר:${data.city}</p>
<p>רחוב:${data.street}</p>
<p>טלפון:${data.phone}
<br></br>
<p>פרטי הזמנה:</p>
<p>כמות בשר:${ingredients.meat}</p>
<p>כמות פסטרמה:${ingredients.pastrama}</p>
<p>כמות סלט:${ingredients.salad}</p>
<br></br>
<p>סה"כ לתשלום:${price}</p>
<p>צורת תשלום:${data.checkbox ? 'מזומן' : 'ביט'}`,
    })
    .then(resp => {
      res.json({ resp });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

app.use(postMail);
app.listen(3001);
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like error is not properly processed by expressjs framework

try

```js
const postMail = router.post('/send', (req, res, next) => { // add `next` here!
  const { data, ingredients, price } = req.body;
  return transporter
    .sendMail({
      to: 'hidden@hidden.com',
      from: 'hidden@hidden.com',
      subject: `הזמנה מ:${data.fullName}`,
      html: `<h3>שלום יש לך הזמנה חדשה !</h3>
<p>פרטי משלוח:</p>
<p>שם:${data.fullName}</p>
<p>עיר:${data.city}</p>
<p>רחוב:${data.street}</p>
<p>טלפון:${data.phone}
<br></br>
<p>פרטי הזמנה:</p>
<p>כמות בשר:${ingredients.meat}</p>
<p>כמות פסטרמה:${ingredients.pastrama}</p>
<p>כמות סלט:${ingredients.salad}</p>
<br></br>
<p>סה"כ לתשלום:${price}</p>
<p>צורת תשלום:${data.checkbox ? 'מזומן' : 'ביט'}`,
    })
    .then(resp => {
      res.json({ resp });
    })
    .catch(next); // change from console.error HERE !!!
});
```

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html